# QML ChartView: custom draw graph

Tags: qt, qml, qchartview

I need to draw a custom time series graph like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ9QZ.png). I tried to use QML [HorizontalStackedBarSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtcharts-horizontalstackedbarseries.html), but I think, it's not effective for this kind of work.

My QML code:

```
    ChartView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    legend.visible: false
    ValueAxis {
        id: axisX
        min: 0
        max: 1
        tickCount: 11
        labelFormat: "%.3f s"
        labelsFont.bold: true
    }
    HorizontalStackedBarSeries {
        id: mySeries
        axisY: BarCategoryAxis {
            categories: ["C1"]
            visible: false
        }
        axisX: axisX
    }
    HorizontalStackedBarSeries {
        id: mySeries2
        axisY: BarCategoryAxis {
            categories: ["C2"]
            visible: false
            labelsVisible: false
        }
        axisX: axisX
    }
    HorizontalStackedBarSeries {
        id: mySeries3
        axisY: BarCategoryAxis {
            categories: ["C3"]
            visible: false
        }
        axisX: axisX
    }
}
```

Fill the graph on C++ just for test:

```
void CbTimingRecordReader::setContactSeries2(QAbstractSeries* ch1Series, QAbstractSeries* ch2Series, QAbstractSeries* ch3Series)
{
    QHorizontalStackedBarSeries* series = qobject_cast<QHorizontalStackedBarSeries*>(ch1Series);
    QHorizontalStackedBarSeries* series2 = qobject_cast<QHorizontalStackedBarSeries*>(ch2Series);
    QHorizontalStackedBarSeries* series3 = qobject_cast<QHorizontalStackedBarSeries*>(ch3Series);

    series->attachedAxes().at(0)->setRange(0, 1);
    QList<QBarSet*> sets;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        QBarSet* set = new QBarSet("");
        set->append(i / 25.0);
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            set->setColor(Qt::transparent);
        else
            set->setColor(Qt::red);
        sets << set;
    }
    series->append(sets);
    sets.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        QBarSet* set = new QBarSet("");
        set->append(i / 25.0);
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            set->setColor(Qt::transparent);
        else
            set->setColor(Qt::blue);
        sets << set;
    }
    series2->append(sets);
    sets.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        QBarSet* set = new QBarSet("");
        set->append(i / 25.0);
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            set->setColor(Qt::transparent);
        else
            set->setColor(Qt::green);
        sets << set;
    }
    series3->append(sets);
    sets.clear();
}
```

The result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn1wF.png)

1. Is it possible to change `QBarSet` width?
2. If the first question answer is **NO**, what can I use to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ9QZ.png) kind of graphs?

Comment: Create a `QPen` (set width https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpen.html#setWidth) and set it on the `QBarSet` https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbarset.html#setPen

Comment: `QPen` doesn't change the  `QBarSet` width, it's only creating a border for bars.